dsYM is missing and crashlytics not showing in firebase
I'm experiencing issues with Firebase Crashlytics in my Flutter iOS app where no dSYM files are found. Despite following various steps to manually add dSYM files, the issue persists. Here are the relevant logs:
[Firebase/Crashlytics] Version 10.15.0
10.15.0 - [FirebaseCore][I-COR000001] Configuring the default app.
fopen failed for data file: errno = 2 (No such file or directory)
Errors found! Invalidating cache...
flutter: The Dart VM service is listening on http://127.0.0.1:57571/g0fsGu56ZlE=/
fopen failed for data file: errno = 2 (No such file or directory)
Errors found! Invalidating cache...
10.15.0 - [FirebaseCore][I-COR000033] Data Collection flag is not set.
10.15.0 - [FirebaseInstallations][I-FIS002000] -[FIRInstallationsIDController createGetInstallationItemPromise], appName: __FIRAPP_DEFAULT
10.15.0 - [FirebaseSessions][I-SES000000] Version 10.15.0. Expecting subscriptions from: [Crashlytics]
10.15.0 - [FirebaseCrashlytics][I-CLS000000] [Crashlytics] Running on iOS Simulator (iPhone), 17.5.0 (23E224)
10.15.0 - [FirebaseCrashlytics][I-CLS000000] Generating Install ID
10.15.0 - [FirebaseCrashlytics][I-CLS000000] Registering Sessions SDK subscription for session data
10.15.0 - [FirebaseSessions][I-SES000000] Registering Sessions SDK subscriber with name: Crashlytics, data collection enabled: true

I have tried the following steps to resolve the issue:

Ensured Crashlytics is set up correctly in my app.
Checked the run script configuration in Xcode.
Verified that Xcode is producing dSYM files.
Used Fastlane to automate downloading and uploading dSYM files.
Cleared the cache and restarted the app.
Updated to the latest version of the Firebase SDK.

Despite these efforts, the issue persists and no dSYMs are found for Version 1.0.9 Build 9.
Environment:

Flutter version: 3.19.0
Xcode version: 15.4
Firebase Crashlytics version: 10.15.0


is it warning or crashing the app?

Did try adding dysm files manually from console

No, how to upload manually ?

dsym : Xcode -> Window -> Organiser -> select archive (right click) -> show in finder -> right click archive in finder -> Show Package Content -> dSYM -> (app name).app.dSYM
open firebase console -> crashlytics -> drag and drop dsym files
you will get the crashes

after trying it out, inform if it worked or not.

How to test app while it is debug mode?

is it work adding dsym file from archive ?

Its not working i have tried by adding dysm manually

I think u r missing something, can please provide more info.

I have manually added, and it is working, i saw in release monitoring, where crashes and some data is there, Thank you so much it is working,

good to hear, cheers
